# Grails command object data binding behaviour on different locales

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, locale

Grails (1.3.7) data binding behaviour differs with locales. It is ok but not works for my case.

```
class XCommand{
    Double value 
    //this value comes from an external service which has no idea about locale so default as en_
    //also it is a hidden value, end user is unaware of it
}
```

If user has a different `Locale` than `en`, this value comes to the controller as a different wrong double value

What is the solution? A custom converter? or changing/restoring locale just around the method invocation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FixedLocaleResolver and set the default locale

Try this (in resource.groovy)

```
localeResolver (FixedLocaleResolver, Locale.ENGLISH) {
  Locale.setDefault (Locale.ENGLISH)
}
```

It will set locale fixed to Locale.ENGLISH

Comment: actually i need to fix the locale for a specific request, where a commandObject binding exists